# Javascript: Functions as properties

Tags: javascript, function

Say I had code like so:

```
function on(loc,type,func){
    loc.addEventListener(type, function(e){
        func(e);
    });
}
```

If I called it like this:

```
on(document.getElementById('test'),"click",function(){
    alert('You clicked!');
});
```

It would work, but I want to be able to call the `on` function like so:

```
document.getElementById('test').on('click', function(){
    alert('You clicked!');
});
```

How can I make it able to be called like so?

Comment: `on` is not a property of DocumentElement. You can't do that.

Comment: How can jQuery have that syntax then?

Comment: It doesn't. It uses its own `$` function, which returns its own object, not document elements.

Comment: Provide the example that you're looking at. The above code is not jQuery.

Comment: jQuery has objects wrapped around the native element objects, which provides methods and other APIs for convenience.

Comment: `$("#foo")` is not the same as `document.getElementById('foo')`.

Comment: Are you doing Jquery or just plain javascript. I think thats what everyone is trying to figure out. Jquery has the ".on" function while javascript alone does not.

Comment: You *could* do `HTMLElement.prototype.on = function() { ... };`, **but** this is very frowned upon, and very bad practice. Modifying native objects could cause coding conflicts if different javascript libraries try to modify the prototype.

Comment: @NormanBreau Ok. That's what I need for my purposes, so thanks. However, I will avoid it in future, but for now I don't use libraries that often.

Comment: @DavidGilliam No I am not using jQuery. I am simply attempting to replicate one of it's functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out, the DocumentElement does not have an `.on()` method. Yet!

You can, however, add one by [extending the prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), adding a new property and making your function available on all Elements. This is quite easy (and I'll provide a trivial example in a moment), but it's also [widely considered to be a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice). So before you try this out, understand that Javascript absolutely does make it possible...but that doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Now, that example:

```
Element.prototype.test = function() {
   console.log("Successfully extended the prototype of a native object!");
}

document.getElementById("footer").test();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this because the DocumentElement does not have a property (or allow you to create one (that I know of)) of your `on` function.

You could get away with doing something similar such as modifying your on function to handle the onlcick event for a given element. I haven't tested the below code but it should give you an idea:

```
function on (element) {
    var obj = {
        clickEvent : function () {
            element.onclick = function () {
                alert("you clicked");
            }
        }
    };
    return obj;

}

var theElement = document.getElementById("test");
on(theElement).clickEvent();
```

Comment: This doesn't suit my purposes and is essentially the same as what I was originally using.

Comment: Actually, it's entirely possible to add such a thing (see my answer) but you don't often see it done because it tends to end badly :)

Comment: Touche, S McCrohan. Touche. Although it isn't a good idea (as you and the original poster mentioned).